# Netbeans 8.2 unsupported Java VM version

Tags: windows-10, installation, java, netbeans

I followed all the instructions provided by my course professor to install Netbeans 8.2 IDE and JDK. In a first moment I installed **JDK 11.0.4**, I setted up **PATH** and after that I tried to install **Netbeans 8.2**. The installer showed up an error message about missing JDK. So I used --extract command and I installed manually successfully.

After installation I executed Netbeans 8.2 but neither *New Project* or *New File* worked. So I figured out by Documentation that this version of Netbeans support at least JDK 8. So I repeated the process and installed JDK 8 version (precisely ***jdk1.8.0_221***). Now all works fine and I can open new projects/files.

So I thought it was better to uninstall Netbeans (because I used an unusual way to install it) and do a cleaner installation. But when executing installer this error pops up.

> **"unsupported java vm version"**

How can I resolve this issue? Tell me if I have to share anything useful to solve.

**EDIT**

Error Message:
[image: Unsupported Java VM Version - Error Message]

---

System Informations:

- OS: Windows 10 Home 64 bit (10.0, build 18362)
- System model: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X530FN_S530FN
- BIOS: X530FN.305
- CPU: Intel(R)Core(TM) i5-8265U
- Memory: 8192MB RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I thought it was better to uninstall Netbeans (because I used an unusual way to install it) and do a cleaner installation. But when executing installer this error pops up.
>
> [image]

You need to install the 32-bit Java 8 VM.  Netbeans 8.2 is a 32-bit application, it not compatiable with the 64-bit Java 8 VM, the error message is simply indicating this fact.  However, if you are actually running Windows 10 32-bit, then I suspect the problem is due to the fact you have Java 8 Update 221 installed instead of an older version.

If that is the case then I suggest just extracting Netbeans from the installer and installing it to the directory of your choice.  **The Netbeans 8.2 installer has not been updated in ages, and will never be updated, if it happens to be checking the version of the Java VM installed on the system.**

I strongly suggest you migrated to [Apache NetBeans 11.1](https://netbeans.apache.org/).  Apache Netbeans (Netbeans is no longer an Oracle project) does not even have an installer.  In order to install it you extract it to the directory you want it to exist in.  **This is really the only thing that the Netbeans 8.2 installer actually did, other than check to see if Java was installed, which is the cause of the error you have recieved.**

> I followed all the instructions provided by my course professor to install Netbeans 8.2 IDE and JDK. In a first moment I installed JDK 11.0.4, I setted up PATH and after that I tried to install Netbeans 8.2. The installer showed up an error message about missing JDK. So I used --extract command and I installed manually successfully.

After installation I executed Netbeans 8.2 but neither New Project or New File worked. So I figured out by Documentation that this version of Netbeans support at least JDK 8. So I repeated the process and installed JDK 8 version (precisely jdk1.8.0_221). Now all works fine and I can open new projects/files.

I suspect you had the 32-bit Java 11 VM originally installed which is the reason Netbeans 8.2 intially launched.  Due to the fact Netbeans does not organically look for Java 9+ you were not able to compile projects.

Comment: Yes I am currently running a 64 bit OS, I updated question with calculator specifics. I will try installing Java VM 32 bit.